# Generating a list of products based on database content

Tags: php, mysql, list, nested-loops

I've created a database which contains one table for each product series, basically I'm trying to list all the distinct models (table rows in each table), in a list where the first row is the table_name. Why does this not work?

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM 
                           INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME 
                           IN ('id') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='products-ropox'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $serie = $row["TABLE_NAME"];
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li class='ldd_heading'><a class='link'
              href='products.php?category=".$serie."'>"
              .ucfirst($serie)."</a></li>";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM $serie 
                              ORDER by model ASC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<li><a href='products.php?category=".$serie.
            "&model=".$row['model']."'>".$row['model']."</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

The first loop works well, but the second query generates an error...

Comment: the second query... it says Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.

Comment: You're overwriting `$row` in the second loop.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_query`. It is deprecated. Use either `mysqli_query` or PDO. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: If i just change the `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query` it doesn't work at all... At least it worked a little bit before

Answer (score 1):

Rename the second `$row` and you need `mysql_fetch_assoc` not `mysql_fetch_array`. If you want to use `mysql_fetch_array` you'll need to use `$row[0]`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('id') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='products-ropox'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $serie = $row["TABLE_NAME"];
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li class='ldd_heading'><a class='link' href='products.php?category=".$serie."'>".ucfirst($serie)."</a></li>";
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM $serie ORDER by model ASC");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                echo "<li><a href='products.php?category=".$serie."&model=".$row2['model']."'>".$row2['model']."</a></li>";
            }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Also a good pratice is to stick a `or die(mysql_error())` after a query to output an error if there is one in your query.

Comment: Still nothing has changed. i recopied your code, and changed 'mysql_fetch_array' to 'mysql_fetch_assoc'

mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

The fun thing if i type the query into the SQL part of phpmyadmin, it works like a charm...

Comment: try echoing out `$query`. There is probably an error in it due to the fact `$serie` isn't being set to anything. I hate when this happens, phpmyadmin fine, on the page broken, greeeeat!

Comment: For some reason it's not even being set. 

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM $serie ORDER by model ASC");`
`echo "<li>".$query." - doh! </li>";`

This just echos " -doh!"

Comment: Tried to add a "or die("not sat")" to the end of the query line. It dies instead of defining $query..

Comment: After a bit of fiddling, I've got to "resourse id #(something)" When I echo the query itself...

Comment: Ah, Finally I've got it working! Turns out there was an old line of code at the top of my page, which selected a specific database which wasn't updated. Such a bummer! Sorry for taking your time :-)